# Bootloader issues due to GCC-4.7.0

Tags: gcc, assembly, bootloader

This is a weird problem. I am having a custom bootloader for MIPS 34Kc processor which was consistently booting my target. This was compiled with GCC-4.2.4. Recently we had moved to GCC-4.7.0 and the bootloader is failing to boot the target all the time.

The optimizations are as below:

```
W_OPTS     = -Wimplicit -Wformat -Werror
CC_OPTS    = -c -O -mips32r2 $(W_OPTS) -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-pic -nostdinc -mno-abicalls
CC_OPTS_16 = -c -O -mips16   $(W_OPTS) -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-pic -nostdinc -mno-abicalls
CC_OPTS_A  = $(CC_OPTS) -D_ASSEMBLER_
```

Any pointers to debug this issue would be helpful.

Comment: Examine the sections in the binary generated with gcc-4.2.4 and gcc-4.7.0.  It's likely that certain sections have been introduced that are causing problems.

Comment: Also see if you have any inline asm and double check they are correct. Slightly wrong constraints can produce good or bad code depending on circumstances.

Comment: I am running hard reboot test on the target and it is seen that when my code is compiled with -mno-branch-likely then it passes the reboot test 75 times whereas without that option reboot test fails after 10 runs ; looks like it has something to do with brnaching.